# Flutter The following _CastError was thrown building Builder: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization, dart-null-safety

I need help, I am using AppLocalization and I get an error when I run my application, it says The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
Null check operator used on a null value.

I have initialized my Applocalization value and it complains, so can anyone please assist in finding where the issue is.

my code below

```
class BottomNavWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialIndex;

  const BottomNavWidget(this.initialIndex, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BottomNavWidgetState();
}

class _BottomNavWidgetState extends State<BottomNavWidget>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  _BottomNavWidgetState();



  final double barHeight = 136.0;
  late List<FavouriteHeaderObserver> favouriteHeaderObservers;

  
  late AppLocalizations _localizations;
}
```

Where I am using my value

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    _items = [
      _buildNavItem(selected_news, unselected_news, _localizations.news_label),
      _buildNavItem(
          selected_videos, unselected_videos, _localizations.video_label),
      _buildNavItem(
          selected_scores, unselected_scores, _localizations.scores_label),
      _buildNavItem(
          selected_sports, unselected_sports, _localizations.sports_label),
      _buildNavMoreIcon(
          selected_more, unselected_more, _localizations.more_label),
    ];
  }
```

I am getting the error in this line:
_localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: remove the null check and late modifier

Comment: Hi, it gives an error if I remove either of them.

Comment: @MrShakila it gives an error when I remove either of them.

Comment: remove the late and defined the empty value

Comment: @MrShakila how do I define the empty value of AppLocalization? please show me

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution guys, my code is okay, I just did not declare AppLocalization on my main app widget, which is why it was throwing the null error because it could not find it.